# Derived pullback

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ of schemes, and a morphism $f:Y'\rightarrow Y$. If $F$ is a sheaf on $X$ which is flat over $Y$, is there a formula for the derived pullback $L f^{'\ast}F$ ?
Here $f^{'}:Y^{'}\times_{Y} X\rightarrow X$ is the induced morphism on the fibre product. In the examples I computed I found $L f^{'\ast}F = f^{'\ast}F$, is this true more generally? When do the higher derived pullbacks vanish?

Comment: Hi @Deriver. Welcome to MO! Can you be more explicit on what you mean by a"formula"? Regarding your second question, clearly in some cases one could try simplifying the derived pullback of a coherent sheaf flat over base, for example when Y' is a closed point of Y(probably this is what you allude to in your post). I guess one practical way to check if $Lf' \ast F$ is a sheaf, is by applying a result like Lemma 3.31 of D. Huybrechts book on F.M.Transforms, to the morphism $f':X \times_Y Y' \rightarrow X$ and $\mathcal{Q}^\bullet=Lf' \ast F$.